# Why would this question prompt "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed."

Tags: support

When asking [this question](https://superuser.com/q/505443/166855) titled "How do you reposition a background custom watermark image in Microsoft Word 2013" I get the message "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed." Why?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it starts with "How do you". Often, this could be considered subjective. Like: "How do you like your waffles?"

Maybe replace it with "How to…" or "How can I…".

<sub>I like mine with maple syrup, for example.</sub>

Comment: Thanks - I've changed it, though it sounds a bit posh now.

Comment: Well, the message doesn't prevent you from posting it, so if you know the question's not subjective, just go ahead and ignore the message.

Comment: I did. But that kind of thing is unsettling unless you are confident you know why it's there. Personally I'd remove the message until its algorithm made fewer false positives, but that's just my feeling.